# What is the WSDL-equivalent of openapi oneOf?

Tags: soap, wsdl, openapi

Currently I need to find out what oneOf from openapi ([oneOf - openapi](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/#oneof)) could look like in WSDL.
The definiton of oneOf is:

> oneOf – validates the value against exactly one of the subschemas

In case of oneOf the documentation says that an (JSON)-object should be valid against only one of the specified schemas. If the object is valid against multiple schemas, it wouldn't be valid/correct.

Unfortunately I am not a WSDL-expert, so I am not sure how you could represent something like oneOf in WSDL. I thought I could do something like this:

Openapi-Example

```
schemas:
  fruit:
     title: fruit
     properties:
        color:
           type: string
     oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/apple'   <- schema with property 'kind'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/banana'  <- schema with property 'count'
```

WSDL-equivalent

```
  <xs:complexType name="Fruit">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="color" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="apple" type="schemas:apple" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="banana" type="schemas:banana" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  Or maybe this one

  <xs:complexType name="Fruit">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="color" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="kind" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="count" type="xs:double" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Maybe it is a workaround, but even both WSDL constructs are not really restricting one of the schemas; as mentioned the object should be only valid against **one** of the specified schemas.

**Does anyone know how you could represent oneOf in WSDL?**

Comment: [`xs:choice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256109(v=vs.100))?